# ORM entity class generator for two languages from common model definition

Tags: java, python, orm

I have one database and want to access it directly using two different languages (Java, Python). I want to define the object relational mappings once and somehow generate the entity classes for Python and Java. Is there any way to do it? Any software that can do it? Maybe there is some common format that I should define the mappings that can be used by tools to generate Java and Python classes.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Create a persistense layer in one languaje java o phyton for example an API REST, or other independet languaje aproach, as persistance layer and access as a client in other any languaje

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option for me. I need two separate persistence layers in two different languages. Thank you for your reply, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting on solving this problem myself.  My plan is to use ActiveObjects (https://bitbucket.org/activeobjects/ao) to define schemas in Java.  This package has support for automatically creating database tables, constraints, etc.

On the Python side I'm going to use Orator (https://orator-orm.com/).  This works out nicely because since Python is a dynamic language, there's no duplication between Python and Java.  You simply point Orator to the tables that you created using ActiveObjects and it builds objects automatically using the metadata.

Note that all of this is somewhat theoretical, I haven't actually implemented.  I'll update this answer if there are any pitfalls.

Comment: Great! Will be watching this question.